# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'float' in ortools

Tags: python, vehicle-routing, or-tools

I am trying to implement a constraint as follows:

```
routing.solver().Add(capacity_dimension.CumulVar(idx) * routing.ActiveVar(idx) >= capacity_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(v)) * 0.5 )
```

It gives error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'float'
```

How can I resolve this?

I tried `capacity_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(v)).Value() * 0.5` on RHS but this kills the kernel.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has already been asked on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759051/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-intvar-and-float-or-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved as follows:

```
2 * capacity_dimension.CumulVar(idx) * routing.ActiveVar(idx) >= capacity_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(v))
```

Comment: Please do not ask the same question on 3 sites. These are the same persons who can answer on all sites

Comment: ok noted. Thanks for pointing it out.